# text to speech natural voice

Tags: sound-design, voice

I have been doing some text to speech recently and I tried finding a natural sounding one. All I have found was AT&T natural voice, which did not sound natural at all. Google's text to speech on Google translate sounds not so bad. Is there a way I can make a robot voice sound more natural? I was thinking maybe autotune but I really do not know, I am a newbie.

Answer (score 3):

The only way that you can sensibly do this is to sample a natural voice and then work out useful edit-points between the phonemes. You cannot - in the vernacular - polish a turd. If it sounds like a robot, then its going to sound like a robot pretty much whatever you do to it.